# Ping routine in MS PowerAutomate

Tags: json, ip, azure-data-factory, ping, power-automate

folks, I am trying to find a way to ping a list of IP addresses one at a time and capture either the "from" IP address, which = success or "Request Timeout" = Failure

Ideally being able to capture this information into a JSON file would be fantastic.

I'm using PowerApps and Data Factories to orchestrate the PINGing if Possible and then to consume the JSON results into a DB. the job would run once a day.

Looking for ideas or examples. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I think PowerAutomate is not a good service for us to implement it. You can do it in [azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) by code.

You can [create a timer trigger azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) with the cron expression `0 0 0 * * *`, the function will triggered to run every day at 00:00:00. Then you can write code in it to ping addresses, please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600698/ping-server-from-azure-function/57601677#57601677) about how to do ping in azure function code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the premium HTTP, you could use a HTTP Head to check websites. I also use a local Powershell Ping, and then import it using FTP.